# How do you keep numbering going when sentences interrupt, and start again from the last number when they finish?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Essentially, I need to have a sequential numbering but adding sentences within which is not numbered, but after each sentence interruption, the numbering needs to resumes from where it left off in the preceding paragraph?

I also need full freedom to edit those sentences. Like center it, bolden it etc.  I have only have used - enumerate and usual headings. If I add a new heading, then the numbering is of course, reset. I'll just provide an exact example of what I'm explaining. Can this be done in Latex.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem allows you do it:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{lipsum}%used for an example text
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1][2]
    \item \lipsum[2][3]
\end{enumerate}

\section{bar}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item \lipsum[3][4]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also consult the fine manual of this package for more interesting options.